# Create a document using only client-side code

Tags: sharepoint, client-side

Is it possible to create a document inside document library using just client-side javascript?
Just a simple text or xml file...

There are examples on how to create/delete a folder or delete a file, or update a document property. And you can do anything you want with list items.

But what if I need to create a document in a document or forms library with ECMAScript object model in SP2010, or calling web services via ajax in MOSS? Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it. You just need to have content of file as a Stream or byte[].
Use [such](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/03/12/uploading-files-using-client-object-model-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) code to create file in library.

Comment: maybe i was confusing by using the term "OM". I mean ECMAScript (JavaScript, JScript) object model. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think [SP.FileCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee553729.aspx) class supports `add` method in Javascript OM

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found there are multiple ways to do it, though all of them are normally used in desktop apps, not in browser.

Here is the list:

1. **RPC**: Simple ajax `POST`ing to `_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll` can do the job quickly if you don't need to set metadata or handle multiple content types
2. **Copy Web Service**: `CopyIntoItems` method of `copy.asmx` service accepts base64-encoded file body
3. **HTTP PUT**: You can simply `PUT` your file to the desired destination, though this method can by unsupported by some browsers